# Multiples event trigger(onClick) inside a recycler view

Tags: java, android, events, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with multiples view, I already  settle all diferent viewholder correctly and some viewholder are represent with the same ViewGroup, inside the viewgroup I have a button when this button is clicke it change the value in a textView until now everything work well, the problem is when I trigger the event some of the all the viewgroup in the list of same view group change when I click one button in not order specifically inside the list but is constant in the instance,I already set some breakpoint but anything out of the normal, any ide why something like this is happen?

my ViewHolder Hirechary look like this.

```
public abstract class AbstractViewHolderR extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

   public Button btn;
   public TextView view; 

   ...
}

public class ChildVH1 extends AbstractViewHolderR{
  ...
}

...other ViewHolder look the same.

/// the event listener look like this.
public class Click implement View.OnClickListener{
   AbstractViewHolderR object;
   public Click(AbstractViewHolderR o){
       object = o;
   }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
     ////error checking omited
     Integer ii = Integer.Parse(object.view.getText().toString);
     ii++;
     object.view.setText(ii.ToString());
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your TextView and Btn to View holder instead and you should add click listener to ViewHolder itself like this

```
public abstract class AbstractViewHolderR extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

         //UPDATE
   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }
   ...
}

public class ChildVH1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
   public Button btn;
   public TextView view; 

   public ChildVH1(View itemView){
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                      //do your stuff
                      //you can use getAdapterPosition() to get current 
                       //position in adapter
                  }
              });
     }
}

}
```

Comment: I tried with another activity and the result is the same result: the activity code is https://gist.github.com/aneury1/667b936b53fd50c6b78c4f4ca4d43de4

Comment: @AneuryPerez Your code is missing 1 important method getItemId(). If you don't add this method then it causes the repetition. 
I updated my answer. please check

Comment: I already implemented this function override with the same result, but finally I realize that my make mistake was not understand that RecyclerView recycle every holder when it need, and in order to get rid of this error I used  the idea of itemId but in another class I took the new class as a model which contain a value for each entry in my list, I set the update value of every holder on onbindviewholder in my adapter maybe is not the best option but this case it work ok. if you have other option I will try it.